# Chequear si existe fila en Oracle y rollback

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Se necesita hacer un script en oracle para insertar unas filas pero para esto se necesita que no existan antes;

No conozco mucho Oracle y lo que desarrolle fue esto.

```
BEGIN 
 IF EXISTS SELECT IDTip, NombreSub FROM Subm WHERE IDTip = 'V' and IDTip = 
 'E'; 
   -- EXIT OR ROLLBACK OR END
 ELSE
    INSERT INTO Subm(IDTip, NombreSub) VALUES ('V','Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO Subm(IDTip, NombreSub) VALUES ('E','ELABORADOR');
     COMMIT;
 END IF;
END;
```

si existe salirse del script si no existen hacer el INSERT INTO y commit no se si este codigo esta bien a lo que requiero.

Comment: Qué sucede cuando ejecutas el script?

Comment: @Alfabravo la pregunta es que instruccion coloco si existe registros? un exit rollback o end??

Comment: No has insertado nada, así que no procede hacer rollback. `END` tampoco procede porque no es el final del bloque de transacción. Lo más fácil sería invertir la condición del IF y validar si NO existe una fila que cumpla con la condición.